# Align button in FieldSet

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using Ext JS 2.3.0 I've created a FieldSet that looks like this

[image]

I would like the Remove Condition button to appear underneath the input fields instead of under the labels, my code is:

```
    var kpiUpper = new Ext.form.TextField({
        fieldLabel: "Higher",
        name: 'upperBound',
        allowBlank: true
    });

    var kpiFilterFieldset = new Ext.form.FieldSet({
        jsonForm: true,
        jsonType: 'object',
        jsonName: 'kpiFilter',
        title: locale['label.kpi.condition'],
        checkboxToggle: true,
        collapsed: true,
        autoHeight:true,
        items : [
             /* code to add first input box and combo box omitted */
            kpiUpper,
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Remove Condition',
            }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
{
            xtype          : 'button',
            text           : 'Remove Condition',
            fieldLabel     : '&nbsp;',
            labelSeparator : ''
 }
```

Comment: Note that it is sufficient to use a plain space `' '` as `fieldLabel`, no need for a nonbreaking space `'&nbsp;'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just can try

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Remove Condition',
    margins: '20 0 0 20'
}
```